# How can I expand YAML anchors and aliases and get the resulting YAML in Bash?

Tags: bash, yaml

I have a `yaml` file, inside which I use anchors & aliases to DRY up the file. It's a `docker-compose` file. Simple e.g. follows:

```
version: "3.4"

x-build: &build
  context: ../

services:
  api:
    build:
      <<: *build
      dockerfile: some-path/Dockerfile
    image: gcr.io/some-project/api
```

I use `yq` and then `jq` to convert this to `json` and pass it to `terraform` so that I can re-use the information in `docker-compose` as a source of truth.

All the aliases and anchors get removed from the resulting `json`. Not a disaster, but it would be much nicer to have it actually expanded.

I'm looking for a command-line tool that I can run in a `bash` script to take the above `json` as an input and expand the anchors and aliases, and write the result to stdout, so something like:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: some-path/Dockerfile
    image: gcr.io/some-project/api
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I doubt Bash is a good language choice for this. This needs a specific tool to make it error-proof. You might make a PR for this: https://github.com/OndraZizka/yaml-merge

Comment: The question in the title (the one in the body is not about programming), is ambigious: do you want to expand using bash and then load in bash, or do you want to expand (e.g. using python/ruby/perl) and then load data from the pre-expanded YAML in bash?

Comment: Thanks I'll clarify in an edit!

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`explode`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/anchor-and-alias-operators) operator from `yq`:

```bash
$ cat example.yaml 
version: "3.4"
x-build: &build
  context: ../
services:
  api:
    build:
      <<: *build
      dockerfile: some-path/Dockerfile
    image: gcr.io/some-project/api

$ yq 'explode(.)' -o json < example.yaml
{
  "version": "3.4",
  "x-build": {
    "context": "../"
  },
  "services": {
    "api": {
      "build": {
        "context": "../",
        "dockerfile": "some-path/Dockerfile"
      },
      "image": "gcr.io/some-project/api"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the rationale for adding `-o json`? The aim is to render a YAML with anchors.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani, the OP said "I use yq and then jq to convert this to json and pass it to terraform so that I can re-use the information in docker-compose as a source of truth.", which to me says they have YAML and want JSON. Of course with `yq` you can have either.

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you taking the yaml as source of truth?
You should have a look on [spruce](https://github.com/geofffranks/spruce). Basically it is a `yaml`/`json` merge tool that can also convert to `json`. However, it also throws your anchors and aliases away.

Convert `yml` to json, thus no need for `yq` and `jq` action anymore :)

```
spruce json
```

Merge `yml` files:

```
spruce merge file1.yml file2.yml
```

Your example:

```
$ spruce merge spruce-input.yml
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: some-path/Dockerfile
    image: gcr.io/some-project/api
version: "3.4"
x-build:
  context: ../

$ spruce json spruce-input.yml | jq -r
{
  "services": {
    "api": {
      "build": {
        "context": "../",
        "dockerfile": "some-path/Dockerfile"
      },
      "image": "gcr.io/some-project/api"
    }
  },
  "version": "3.4",
  "x-build": {
    "context": "../"
  }
}
```

Comment: [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is not the same as [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and [recommended file extension](http://yaml.org/faq.html) for YAML files has been `.yaml` at least since [Sep 2006](https://web.archive.org/web/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html).

Comment: `yml` in place of `yaml` seems to be a Windows platform disease.